# Should I pass the full condition to the Select SQL query that I want to filter results based on it, or just get the data and filter them in php?

Tags: php, sql, database

This question is more related to the speed and making the website function faster by choosing the good thing and faster thing for it to do.

So, should I do the filtration in php after selecting the data from database based on unique identifier like ID or something like below

```
$select_data_from_database = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM forchecking WHERE id = :id");
$select_data_from_database->execute(
    array(
        ":id" => $id
    )
);
$results = $select_data_from_database->fetch();
if ($results) {
    $now = time();
    if ($results['reviewingStart'] == null || $now >= $results['reviewingStart']) {
        // Some code
    } else {
        // Some other code
    }
}
```

Or should I just pass the conditions to the SQL Select query itself and let it do the filtration to me like this

```
$select_data_from_database = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM forchecking WHERE id = :id AND ( reviewingStart IS NULL OR reviewingStart <= :now)");
$select_data_from_database->execute(
    array(
        ":id" => $id,
        ":now" => time()
    )
);
$results = $select_data_from_database->fetch();
if ($results) {
    // Some code
} else {
    // Some other code
}
```

I am asking about what is better to do that will result in a faster performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should pass the filtering conditions *into* the database.  There are two very important reasons:

- Filtering reduces the number of rows returned by the database, which improves performance.
- The SQL query can be optimizes to return the rows that you want.  One common optimization is using indexes to look up the values directly, but there are others.

In your particular case, it does not really matter.  If the `id` is unique, then at most one row will be returned.  Generally, there is little difference between returning one row and no rows.  And, if the `id` is a primary key, that index will be used anyway to retrieve the row.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is what I thought. So, in my case right now, because the ID is unique that it will give me only one row, it does not matter.